# Non Permissible values of $\cot(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Why is it that the non-permissible values of cotangent $x$ is only where $\sin(x) = 0$ and not also where $\cos(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

I believe that one way you can see this is that
$$\cot x = \frac{1}{\tan x} = \frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} = \frac{\cos x }{\sin x}$$
which is $0$ when $\cos x = 0$, and undefined when $\sin x=  0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\cot{x} = \frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}$ by definition.  It's okay to have $0$ in the numerator but not in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent of $x$ is defined as the the sine of $x$ divided by the cosine of $x$, so $$\tan x= \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$

If $x = 0$ then product is $0/1 = 0$, which is a real solution.

However for $$\cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$

Now, if $x = 0$, then the product is $1/0$ which is undefined, meaning that a solution does not exist, which means that $\sin x$ cannot be equal to 0 for $\cot x$ to exist.